# The set of the points along the line joining two end points in a vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

The definition of a convex set $K$ is that: Whenever $x, y \in K$, the line connecting $x,y$ will also belong to $K$, meaning all the points of the form:
$$
ax+(1-a)y,\space\space\space\space\space\space\space 0\le a \le 1
$$

My question is: Why do the points along the line joining $x,y$ have this formula?

Comment: did you try plotting a few points in say in the plane to get some intuition?

Comment: What is your definition of "line connecting $x,y$"? By the way, what does that question have to do with functional analysis?

Comment: @user251257 This definition was taken from my functional analysis textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(x-y) is a vector pointing from y to x. To find a point on the line interval xy, start from y, and move in a straight line towards x, i.e. along the vector (x-y). If 'a' is the proportion of the distance from y to x that you move, then you are at:

y + a(x - y) = y + ax - ay = ax + (1 - a)y

You can also interpret the equation more directly as the weighted average of x and y (where 'a' is the weight). That all weighted averages of x and y lie on a line between x and y may or may not be self apparent, but either way one will help you remember the other.